# Merge and Dissolve Tool in Arcgis 10.5 not working

Tags: arcgis-desktop, background-geoprocessing

The Merge and Dissolve tools in Arcgis 10.5 are not working for me. I did not get any error messages, but the merged layer does not get added to the map.
here is a screenshot : 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As [commented](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/291286/merge-and-dissolve-tool-in-arcgis-10-5-not-working#comment467127_291286), the original poster was able to solve this problem by turning off background geoprocessing.

> Geoprocessing > geoprocessing options > uncheck background geoprocessing.